# Achieve total anonymity on public wifi using Android

Tags: android, anonymity

Would this be enough to achieve total anonymity on public wifi with an Android device:

- use Orbot
- spoof your MAC address
- turn off location services
- turn off cellular data

Are there any other services that should be disabled?  For example under 'Running services,' I see 'Android Core Apps,' 'Google services,' etc.

How would we do the following:

- turn off GPS (I can ask this question on the Android exchange if this doesn't belong here)
- emergency calls, such as 911, can be use without cellular data.  Is emergency call tracking information continuously transmitted?  If so, is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: This is way too broad, in particular because no one can define _total anonymity_ in such a way that it can be achieved. For example, no matter what you do, WiFi chips have unique quirks that allow them to be identified, even if you spoof the MAC address. I believe there was a paper a year or two ago showing this.

Comment: I see, so the transmit pattern could give away the manufacturer/model.  But the original MAC would still not be visible, correct?

Comment: The original MAC itself would not be visible, assuming no vulnerabilities. But since vulnerabilities exist, _absolute_ anonymity is still impossible.

Comment: Apart from that Orbot by default only protects services which are explicitly configured to use it (i.e. proxy settings). In general I doubt that you can the level of anonymity you are trying to achieve with a stock android phone where play services etc are running. You might reach a level where the owner of the Hotspot can not figure out by its own who you are but for example Google still knows who you are.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Could you clarify what you mean by your first sentence? I understand that if you browse the web using Google with Orbot, they will still know who you are because of their pixel, but if you use a private tab, Google shouldn't know who you are, correct?

Comment: @user2233706: *"...if you browse the web..."* - Your question is about Android not about browsing only. There is more network activity going on with Android apart from browsing. And I refer to this other activity.

Comment: Does Orbot also handle this other network activity?

Comment: @user2233706 usually not. It can be configured to try to capture all traffic on a rooted device but you can't be sure that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with your phone manufacturers OS you can never be sure what is running and which applications send data where.

So as a first step you have to install a operating system where you can know what is inside. The best choice would be [Replicant](http://replicant.us/) because it is 100% free software and you can get the source code for all parts of it.

Because Replicant supports a very limited number of devices, you might have to resort to [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/). Some parts of it are non-free, so you can never be 100% sure what it does, but still a lot better than your stock OS. Under no circumstances install the Google Apps package!

Then you switch the phone to flight mode and disable GPS and WiFi location services. Then you switch your MAC address and then enable only WiFi.

You can then surf the internet with Orbot and Orfox somewhat safe.

This will prevent websites from knowing where you are. Of course you still have to be very careful to not enter any personal details in any form on a website. Also, of course, you can only use Orfox to browse the web, never download any other apps and run them.

Comment: Suppose I just want to browse the web anonymously.  Do I need to install a custom OS?

Comment: @user2233706 that depends on exactly your requirements. Without a custom OS you can never be sure what information is transmitted and to whom. Almost certainly your location is sent to google and probably your phones manufacturer.

Answer (score -1):

- Use a custom roms (AOSP) without Google Apps.
- Use VPNs like Cyberghost, psiphon or use proxy app orbot because it also bypass the censorships
- Ghostery will protect you from 13 to 15 third party tracking services.
- And last don't expect total anonymity.

Comment: Orbot uses Obfsproxy. Is that enough to bypass censorships?

Comment: @user2233706 If your ISP is censoring connections to the Tor network, obfsproxy should be enough to bypass said censorship.